# Button Does not Change Colour on Hover

Tags: html, css

I have a css class assigned to a button like this:

```css
.button {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 96%;
  height: 48px;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  color: #232856;
  border: 1px solid #3d8b40;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #f1f1f1
}

.button a {
  color: #232856;
  text-decoration: none
}

.button a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background: #232856
}
```

The `.button` works perfectly, does everything I need it to do.

But the `a` and `a:hover` parts do nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show me the HTML code?

Comment: Even though the code in the answers might work - buttons are basically meant to submit forms. So there is no need to wrap an a tag with a button tag. If you want a link in "button style" set the css of your a tag to display: inline-bock; and append all styles inclusive hover directly to it.

Comment: Thank you Luckyfella, useful info.  My button is not inside a form, it's just a link.  I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the a: hover and instead just use the `button: hover {`
Here is the code:

```
 .button {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 96%;
  height: 48px;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  color: #232856;
  border: 1px solid #3d8b40;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #f1f1f1
}

.button a {
  color: #232856;
  text-decoration: none
}

.button:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background: #232856
}
```

That should work. When you need something with a hover effect such as a button, you dont need to include the a:, just write button: hover

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might forgot about class for button, if you want to do it general then use `button` in styles instead of `.button`.

Also you forgot about semicolon after `text-decoration: none`, so this lane and every css style below in same block scope is not applied.

```css
.button {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 96%;
  height: 48px;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  color: #232856;
  border: 1px solid #3d8b40;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.button a {
  color: #232856;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background: #232856;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <a href="#">My a inside button<a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
.button:hover a{
// styling when on hover
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I broke my BUTTON!

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.btn {
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#606dbc,#606dbc 10px,#465298 10px,#465298 20px);
  height: 600%;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: gold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Hover Over Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```